# line-height in wordpress menu

Tags: menu, css

I am trying to put a `line-height` to properly align all menu items in a wordpress menu. My problem is that it works with menus that do not have an image or description, if it does have a image or description it does not align vertically with the `line-height` property.

Here's what I have for the menu items working:

```
.menu-dropdown a.level1 > span, .menu-dropdown span.level1 > span {
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Now when I use Firebuf to try and fix the problem, there is a class showing a little diferent, which is "level1 parent". Even with Firebug I cannot fix this. I´m working on localhost, so can't give a link for the problem, but if it's necessary I'll put it online.

Here´s the link, you can see the problem in main menu at the top: 
http://ricardo.dyndns-at-work.com:8888/yootheme/

Comment: Can you put a jsFiddle online?

Comment: Please see the link to the site i´ve posted on main post. Thanks